# Setting Covariance to Zero in Lavaan

Tags: r, analysis, covariance, r-lavaan, structural-equation-model

In `lavaan` in `R`, when using the `sem()` function, the covariance values are automatically populated. However, I want to force one of the covariance values to be zero while using the `sem()` function, i.e. without moving to the manual `lavaan()` function.

How can that be done?

Comment: I think this question should be migrated to [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Have a look at pg9/10 of Lavaan: an R package for structural equation modeling and more Version 0.3-1 [ http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.unt.edu%2Frss%2Fclass%2FJon%2FMiscDocs%2Flavaan1.pdf&ei=FJNKU5DpJMyg7AaM-oGADw&usg=AFQjCNHZM8gAcmHf68gz2LNBndImlUB3Wg]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See http://lavaan.ugent.be/tutorial/syntax2.html

I'm just copying from there, the following code is self-explanatory

```
# three-factor model
   visual =~ x1 + x2 + x3
  textual =~ x4 + x5 + x6
  speed   =~ NA*x7 + x8 + x9
# orthogonal factors
   visual ~~ 0*speed
  textual ~~ 0*speed
# fix variance of speed factor
    speed ~~ 1*speed
```

Note that the fist loadings on each latent factor are, by default, fixed to 1 - if you want to estimate them, you would use something like NA*x7  as above. And fixing a covariance to zero is done with something like `visual ~~ 0*speed` -- if you don't include this line, the covariances between latent variables are automatically included in the model.

The lavaan homepage is a very good source on lavaan.

Comment: Thank you for your reply regarding the covariance, exactly what I needed. But regarding your comment, "Note that the fist loadings on each latent factor are, by default, fixed to 0...", I'm not sure that's right; if you are using the sem() or cfa() functions, the loadings would be estimated for each of x1, x2, x3, x4, etc...

Correct me if I'm wrong though.

Comment: Yes, and no. I made a stupid mistake (now corrected!) - the first loading is not fixed to *0*, it's fixed to *1*. Look at http://lavaan.ugent.be/tutorial/syntax2.html, the first paragraph.  The loading for x1 is (by default) not estimated, it is fixed to 1 - if you don't want this, you need the `NA*x1` trick.

Comment: I think the difference in our approaches is the many pre-loaded arguments that come along with the sem() shell of lavaan() which allows for such loadings to be calculated automatically even without the NA. But again, when I noticed your "(by default)" it made sense to me.